# How to write an install script for ubuntu

Tags: linux, installation

I just developed an opengl game in linux (ubuntu).. Now I would like to write a setup script for the same which installs the game directly into the apt using the command..

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

so that it runs from anywhere throughout linux without going into the specified folder for the game. Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/02/05/how-to-create-a-debian-deb-package/

http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-create-debianubuntu-package-deb.html

http://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -eu -o pipefail # fail on error , debug all lines

    sudo -n true
    test $? -eq 0 || exit 1 "you should have sudo priveledge to run this script"

    echo installing the must-have pre-requisites
    while read -r p ; do sudo apt-get install -y $p ; done < <(cat << "EOF"
        perl
        zip unzip
        exuberant-ctags
        mutt
        libxml-atom-perl
        postgresql-9.6
        libdbd-pgsql
        curl
        wget
        libwww-curl-perl
    EOF
    )

    echo installing the nice-to-have pre-requisites
    echo you have 5 seconds to proceed ...
    echo or
    echo hit Ctrl+C to quit
    echo -e "\n"
    sleep 6

    sudo apt-get install -y tig
```