# How to create a .deb of a single Python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, packaging, deb

I've created a GUI frontend in Python for playing and recording audio streams and would like to create a .deb file so my friends can easily install the script on their Ubuntu systems. This is my first time attempting to create a .deb file and so far I'm a bit confused by all the different tutorials on the web. The script consists of a single Python file (urlplayer.py) and depends on mplayer and python-tk. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to this and would really appreciate any help or links which will point me in the right direction.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 2):

The best documentation, although not the friendliest, is the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/).  You could always pop into #debian-mentors on irc://irc.oftc.net for help if your stuck after reading the guide.

Comment: [More links here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807843/how-to-write-an-install-script-for-ubuntu/4807936#4807936).

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this extensive tutorial seems to be focused on more complex programs with multiple files which must be compiled in certains ways. My project only consists of a single python script and doesn't need compiling. I hoping someones knows a simplified Python specific tutorial, or maybe some sort of script. (tried Google, no luck)

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/hpfem/hermes/wiki/Create-.deb-Package-for-Femhub

See also [Making a deb from a python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770883/making-a-deb-from-a-python-file)